# Predicting the tension in the rod of a pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity, oscillators

I'm trying to predict the tension in a pendulum with radius/length $r=0.4m$, mass of $m=0.1kg$, and dropped from an angle $\theta=15^\circ$. Also, I'm trying to find the tension at the lowest point of the swing, so at angle $0$. Obviously, this equation will be needed: $$T={{mv^2}\over r}+mg$$ and then to find the velocity I will use the energy of conservation and get this: $$v=\sqrt{2gh}$$
Which is explained here: http://physics.bu.edu/~redner/211-sp06/class-energy/pendulum.html

My question is, would this be the correct way to go about getting the tension? Would this give an incorrect value? I'm just not entirely sure if this is correct.

Also, just to be sure, I'm trying to find the tension at the lowest point of the swing, when the angle is zero at the bottom.

EDIT: I forgot, to get $h$ I will use $y=rcos \theta$ when theta equals 15 degrees.

Comment: Hint: Find the tension needed to keep the mass moving in an arc with radius $r$.

Comment: is the angle from vertical or horizontal?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you approach this and most problems in dynamics, step by step.

1. **Kinematics** - Describe the motion(s) of the centers of mass. In this case the center of mass moves in an arc described by the angle $\theta$, and I am placing a coordinate system on the pivot of the pendulum.

   - Let's call the location vector of the object as $$\boldsymbol{pos} = \pmatrix{r \sin \theta \\  - r  \cos\theta } $$
   - And by direct differentiation we get the velocity $$ \boldsymbol{vel} = \pmatrix{ r \dot{\theta} \cos \theta \\ r \dot{\theta} \sin\theta } $$
   - and the acceleration $$ \boldsymbol{acc} = \pmatrix{ r \ddot{\theta} \cos \theta - r \dot{\theta}^2 \sin\theta \\ r \ddot{\theta} \sin\theta - r \dot{\theta}^2 \cos\theta } $$

<sub>where $\dot{\theta}$ is the time derivative of $\theta$ and $\ddot{\theta}$ the time derivative of $\dot{\theta}$. So the speed is $v = r \dot{\theta}$ always.</sub>

2. **Free Body Diagram** - Describe the forces acting on the body $$  \boldsymbol{F} = \pmatrix{-T \sin \theta  \\ T \cos\theta - m g } $$

<sub>Here $T$ is the tension and $g$ the acceleration of gravity.</sub>

3. **Equations of Motion** - Apply Newton's equations of motion to relate the tension $T$ to the motion of the object

$$ \boldsymbol{F} = m \, (\boldsymbol{acc}) $$
$$ \pmatrix{-T \sin \theta  \\ T \cos\theta - m g } = m \pmatrix{ r \ddot{\theta} \cos \theta - r \dot{\theta}^2 \sin\theta \\ r \ddot{\theta} \sin\theta - r \dot{\theta}^2 \cos\theta } $$

4. **General Solution** These are two equations, do be solved for $T$ and $\ddot{\theta}$ that will give the the tension and the angular acceleration.

$$ \begin{aligned} T & = m ( g \cos\theta + r \dot{\theta}^2 ) \\ \ddot{\theta} & = - \frac{g}{r} \sin \theta \end{aligned} $$

4. **Speed from energy** - The height drop from $\theta_0 = 15°$ to the lowest part is $h = [- r \cos(\theta_0)]-[-r  \cos(0)] = r-r \cos(\theta_0) $ so the speed $v = r \dot{\theta}$ is

$$ \left. \frac{1}{2} v^2 = g h \right\} v = \sqrt{2 g h} $$

This gives us the value of $\dot{\theta} = \sqrt{ \frac{2 g  \left(1-\cos(\theta_0)\right)}{r}} $ at the bottom of the swing $\theta=0$ to be used in the equation for the tension.

5. **Specific Solution** - Use the angle speed above in the general solution to find the tension at the specific time frame (bottom of swing).

$$T = m g \bigl( 3 -2 \cos(15°) \bigr)$$

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. In your first equation T is the total force or apparent weight of the "Bob" at the bottom of its swing, which is a combination of the centrifugal forces generated by the swinging pendulum plus the normal gravitational force.

A pendulum is easy to imagine if you a normal Cartesian plane with the normal anticlockwise measurement of angle, and then rotate your plane 90 degrees clockwise so that you are measuring the angle from the vertical.

The height (h) the Bob falls would then be r(1- cos theta) not as you have listed above as rcos theta, it is correctly mentioned in the web link you have provided.

I did some experiments years ago on this problem. If you limit how high you lift the Bob to a maximum of 90 degrees from vertical then the Bob appears to weigh three times as much as just hanging. A result that I found surprising at first.